# Yahoo API POST with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, yahoo-api

I am working with the yahoo fantasy sports API (http://developer.yahoo.com/fantasysports/guide)and trying to add a player by sending a post request with a specific league/team/player in the query string. For some reason even though I have tried a number of ways to specify this request as a post rails is making a GET request. Would anyone be able to provide me some ideas on how to troubleshoot this? Thank you!

```
Route:
  resources :free_agents do
    post 'add_nfl_player', :on => :collection
   end

Method:
 def add_nfl_player
  request_url= "my query string"                                                                                            
  access_token = session[:access_token]
  response = access_token.request(:post, request_url)
  data = Hash.from_xml(response.body)
  render :json => data
 end
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see, this API only supports GET requests.  I could be wrong, though.

Have you looked at gems like `rest_client` (https://github.com/archiloque/rest-client)?  I'm not sure I really follow the code you put up.   If `rest_client` doesn't work for you, try a more general HTTP client like HTTParty (https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty).

Regards,

Kyle